# Stripe Session Object with iterations (total installments)

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, subscription

I'm trying to generate Payment URL for the Subscription wtih following

**Use case:**
*Create a Subscription link with $1000 to pay every 2 months in 4 intervals. This means each installment customer will pay $250*

- First Payment: 12th Jul 2023 (NOW/Today)
- Second Payment: 12th Sep 2023
- Third Payment: 12th Nov 2023
- Fourth and last Payment: 12th Jan 2024

Code:
Create SubscriptionSchedule

```
log.info("Price Creation");

Map<String, Object> recurring = new HashMap<>();

recurring.put("interval", recurringInterval);

recurring.put("interval_count", recurringIntervalCount);

Map<String, Object> priceParams = new HashMap<>();

priceParams.put("unit_amount", eachInstallmentAmount);

priceParams.put("currency", "usd");

priceParams.put("recurring", recurring);

priceParams.put("product", product.getId());


Price price = Price.create(priceParams);

log.info("PriceID: "+price.getId());


List<Object> phases = new ArrayList<>();   

List<Object> items = new ArrayList<>();


log.info("item creation");

Map<String, Object> singleItem = new HashMap<>();

singleItem.put(

"price",

price.getId()

);

singleItem.put("quantity", 1);    


log.info("add singleItem to items");

items.add(singleItem);


log.info("create singlePhase");

Map<String, Object> singlePhase = new HashMap<>();

singlePhase.put("items", items);

singlePhase.put("iterations", iterations);

log.info("add singlePhase to phases");

phases.add(singlePhase);


log.info("create subscriptionParams");

Map<String, Object> subscriptionParams = new HashMap<>();

subscriptionParams.put("customer", customer.getId());

subscriptionParams.put("end_behavior", "release");

subscriptionParams.put("phases", phases);

SubscriptionSchedule subscriptionSchedule =

SubscriptionSchedule.create(subscriptionParams);
```

Till here, everything is good. I would like to redirect payment with the help of **SubscriptionSchedule**

Session objects have to create checkout links, but it doesn't support iteration(no.of installments).

I didn't find any relation to the Session with SubscriptionSchedule to map.

Can you please help on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing some issues here.  When you create a [Checkout Session](https://site-admin.stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/how-checkout-works) it generates a link to direct your customers to a Stripe hosted UI for collecting payment method information and confirming the payment.  You can use the Checkout Session to create [Subscriptions](https://site-admin.stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/overview) by setting the [mode](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/overview) to `"subscription"`.

However, that is *not* directly related to [SubscriptionSchedules](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules).  When you create a Subscription Schedule it will create an underlying Subscription object as well as schedule updates based on the phases you define.  It does not create a Checkout Session.  *However* it **does** create an [Invoice](https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing/overview) and this means you have the option to use the [Hosted Invoice Page](https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing/hosted-invoice-page) to collect payment method data.

To get this from your SubscriptionSchedule object you want to follow the relationships by using the [expand feature](https://stripe.com/docs/expand) of the API.  Specifically when you create the Sub Schedule you will want to pass `"subscription.latest_invoice"`.  This will mean your Sub Schedule will include both the subscription and latest invoice objects by default.  From there you can get the `hosted_invoice_url` from the Invoice object and use that to collect payment from your customers.